# How does "g" in RegExp test method works alternatively?

Tags: javascript, regex

http://jsfiddle.net/bpt33/

```
var t = "";

var a = ["atom-required","atom-label","atom-data-type","atom-regex"];

var r = /atom\-(label|required|regex|data\-type|class|is\-valid|field\-value|error)/i;

function test(a, r){
    for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        t += a[i] + " => " + r.test(a[i]) + "<br/>";
    }
}

test(a, r);

t += "<br/>";

a = ["atom-required","atom-label","atom-data-type","atom-regex"];

var r = /atom\-(label|required|regex|data\-type|class|is\-valid|field\-value|error)/gi;

test(a, r);

$("#results").get(0).innerHTML = t;
```

When g is not specified, it works correctly,

```
atom-required => true
atom-label => true
atom-data-type => true
atom-regex => true
```

When g is specified, it works alternatively

```
atom-required => true
atom-label => false
atom-data-type => true
atom-regex => false
```

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to escape `-` - it's only special in a character class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because with the `g` modifier, the regexp becomes stateful, and resumes the next search at the index after the last match.

When no match is found, it resets itself.

You can observe the starting point by using the [`.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property.

```
r.lastIndex; // 0 or some higher index
```

You can reset it manually by setting that property to `0`.

```
r.lastIndex = 0
```

Comment: "When no match is found, it resets itself" and returns false

Comment: @thejh: Yes, the `test()` method naturally returns `false` when no match is found.

Comment: Actually, it makes very little (close to zero, I'd say) sense using `/g` modifier on the pattern that is to be used in `.test` - unless you indeed want the regex to advance. But that's VERY rare, to say the least.

Comment: @raina77ow: Unless you want to test for multiple matches on the same string in a loop, and stop the testing when a certain quantity is found.